# Why is only the root logger working in Log4j 2 with JSON config?

Tags: java, json, log4j2

I've run into an issue trying to log into a log file and the console using Log4j 2.

I'm using JSON configuration, which is loaded just fine. My configuration (log4j2.json) in its entirety is as follows:

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "appenders": {
            "Console": {
                "name": "consoleAppender",
                "PatternLayout": {
                    "pattern": "%d{DEFAULT} %-5p [%t]: %m%n"
                }
            },
            "File": {
                "name": "fileAppender",
                "fileName": "log.txt",
                "PatternLayout": {
                    "pattern": "%d{DEFAULT} %-5p [%t]: %m%n"
                }
            }
        },
        "loggers": {
            "logger":
            {
                "name": "fileLogger",
                "level": "info",
                "appender-ref": { "ref": "fileAppender" }
            },
            "root": {
                "level": "info",
                "appender-ref": { "ref": "consoleAppender" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested logging with the following class:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggingTest {
    static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LoggingTest.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.trace("A trace log from " + LoggingTest.class.getName() + ".main(String[])");
        log.debug("A debug log from " + LoggingTest.class.getName() + ".main(String[])");
        log.info("An info log from " + LoggingTest.class.getName() + ".main(String[])");
        log.warn("A warn log from " + LoggingTest.class.getName() + ".main(String[])");
        log.error("An error log from " + LoggingTest.class.getName() + ".main(String[])");
        log.fatal("A fatal error log from " + LoggingTest.class.getName() + ".main(String[])");
    }
}
```

When executed the console, as expected, contains the following messages:

```
2014-09-15 14:40:42,411 INFO  [main]: An info log from LoggingTest.main(String[])
2014-09-15 14:40:42,412 WARN  [main]: A warn log from LoggingTest.main(String[])
2014-09-15 14:40:42,412 ERROR [main]: An error log from LoggingTest.main(String[])
2014-09-15 14:40:42,412 FATAL [main]: A fatal error log from LoggingTest.main(String[])
```

The log file log.txt is created, but remains empty. I've also tried using the RollingFileAppender with the exact same outcome. I tried changing the loggers' appender-refs:

```
{
    "name": "fileLogger",
    "level": "info",
    "appender-ref": { "ref": "consoleAppender" }
},
"root": {
    "level": "info",
    "appender-ref": { "ref": "fileAppender" }
}
```

In this case nothing is logged into the console but the log file will receive the log messages.

Am I getting something wrong with the config or what is this about?

Comment: You have assigned the `fileAppender` to a `Logger` named `fileLogger`. Unless you do `LogManager.getLogger("fileLogger")` you have not created this logger and nothing will be logger to the file.

Comment: Ah, I see. How do I need to change the config to get the log entries to end up in both of the appenders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
    "loggers": {
        "logger":
        {
            "name": "fileLogger",
            "level": "info",
            "appender-ref": { "ref": "fileAppender" }
        },
        "root": {
            "level": "info",
            "appender-ref": { "ref": "consoleAppender" }
        }
    }
```

You have a `root` logger which is attached to the `consoleAppender` - i.e. all (additive) logging goes to the console. You also have a logger named `fileLogger` whose logging goes to the `fileAppender`. This means that unless you do:

```
LogManager.getLogger("fileLogger")
```

To get the logger named `fileLogger` you are never going to see any output in the file. I'm not sure what `fileLogger` is supposed to achieve, but I think you need to read the documentation on [hierarchical logging and additive logging](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) as you seem to have misunderstood what the `logger` config element does.

In order to assign two appenders to the root logger simply use an array of appenders in the `appender-ref` declaration like so:

```
  "loggers": {
     "root": {
        "level":"info",
        "appender-ref": [{ "ref":"fileAppender" }, { "ref":"consoleAppender" }]
     }
  }
```

Comment: The config provided also only logs to the console, which, when you think about it is logical; there are two values associated with the same key. I've, however, found the solution: a single appender-ref, which contains an array containing both of the ref objects: "appender-ref": [{ "ref": "consoleAppender" }, { "ref": "fileAppender" }]}. Change your answer to that, and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to convert the XML config to JSON - should have run a test to be sure.